React Native: Bottom Tab Navigator shifts up when keyboard is open
I'm working on a React Native project where I use a bottom tab navigator.
When I open the keyboard on a page without the bottom tab, and then navigate back to a tab navigator page using a gesture, the bottom tab shifts up by the height of the keyboard.
I used

react-native: "0.72.10",
react-native-screens: "^3.22.1",
@react-navigation/bottom-tabs: "^6.5.11",


Use this property tabBarHideOnKeyboard
Bottom Tabs Navigator : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/
   <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Wifi"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Config.themeColor,
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard : true,
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'lightgray',
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Config.themeColor,
        },
        tabBarStyle:{backgroundColor:Config.themeColor}
      }}>

